# Guava dependency error

Tags: android, gradle, guava

I added "guava" dependency to one of the modules in my project.
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'

I can build and run unit tests and instrumentation test on the module by building it.

But when i try to build full project, it fails with an error

Error:Execution failed for task ':ui:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/proj/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/samjithsadasivan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/25.1-android/bdaab946ca5ad20253502d873ba0c3313d141036/guava-25.1-android.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-25.1-android.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))

Has anyone seen this ?
gradlew app:dependencies does not show guava present anywhere else in my project.

Comment: it's a library clash

Comment: show me your build.gradle file

Comment: Possibly hitting [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:module_replacement)?